# How to input different numbers with Java

Tags: java

The question is to Write a program that sorts three integers. The integers are entered from the input dialogs and stored in variables num1, num2, and num3, respectively. The program sorts the numbers so that num1 <= num2 <= num3.

actually I do that but the result is available only to 1 ,2 and 3 numbers !

When I enter any different number it doesn't show me the result I want it !

here is my code..

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class number order {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 int num1;
 int num2;
 int num3;

    String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "input NUM 1 " );
           num1 = Integer.parseInt(n);
    String u = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "input NUM 2 " );
         num2 = Integer.parseInt(u);
    String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "input NUM 3 " );
        num3 = Integer.parseInt(m);

    if (num1<=num2&& num2<=num3)
        System.out.println( num1+"<="+ num2+"<="+num3 );
    if(num2<=num1&&num1<=num3)
        System.out.println(num2+"<="+num1+"<="+num3);
    if (num3<=num1&&num1<=num2)
        System.out.println(num3+"<="+num1+"<="+num2);


    // TODO code application logic here
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Do you mean that the program can only accept 3 numbers as input (and not, e.g., four or five)? Or do you mean that the "sorting" works only for certain inputs but not for others?

Comment: I mean the sorting works only for certain inputs which are ( 1,2 and 3 ) ..

Comment: Just to make this clear, if you input, say, 6, 2, and 9, the sorting does not work?

Comment: yes exactly and when I input 1,2and 3 it works .. 1<=2<=3 .. but other numbers are not

Comment: Could you check this again? There's nothing in your code which would restrict input to integers 1,2,3. In fact, 6,2,9 (in this order) should be sorted just fine.

Comment: ok just a minute I'll try these three numbers ..Thx

Comment: @Eng. Your code has no problem at all. It is working fine. even for 6,2,99 it is giving me proper output.

Comment: oh , really it works .. but I just try these number ( 5 , 2 , 4 ) .. it doesn't work !!

Comment: @Eng. Yes, that's because your if-statements cover just three out of six possible arrangements. In particular, you never check whether num1 is the biggest.

Comment: @tobias_k .. yes thanks , I'll try to put all possible and check that

Comment: @tobias_k sorry I don't notice  your below replying and I think your solution is the best .. So, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you check only three out of six possible arrangements of those three numbers. Also note that, even for those three, you are not actually *sorting* the numbers, but only printing them in sorted order, i.e., you are never reassigning the variables `num1`, `num2`, and `num3`.

Just as an alternative to checking all the possible arrangements of the three numbers or  implementing a full sorting algorithm, you can also compare and swap *pairs* of numbers. This way, you get away with far fewer comparisons while still being able to sort all permutations of three numbers.

- if num1 > num2, swap num1 and num2
- if num2 > num3, swap num2 and num3
- if num1 > num2, swap num1 and num2 again

After those three swaps, the numbers are in sorted order.

Of course, if you have more than three numbers this gets impractical, and you should rather implement a full sorting algorithm (for exercise) or go with one of the builtins, like `Arrays.sort` (for real life).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't checked all cases:

```
1 < 2 < 3
1 < 3 < 2
2 < 1 < 3
2 < 3 < 1
3 < 1 < 2
3 < 2 < 1
```

However to check all case like that is not to useful.
an sorted array would be more easy:

```
int arr[3]={num1,num2,num3}
java.utils.Arrays.sort(arr);
println(arr[0] + "<=" + arr[1] + "<=" + arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] all = new int[]();
num1 = Integer.parseInt(n);
all[0] = num1;
num2 = Integer.parseInt(u);
all[1] = num1;
num3 = Integer.parseInt(m);
all[2] = num1;
for(int i=0; i <all.length ;i++){
  if(i!=0 && all[i]< all[i-1]){
     temp = all[i-1];
     all[i-1] = all[i];
     all[i] = temp; 
  }
}
```

all will have sorted array 
or more simply

2 steps
1)add all to a array.
2) call `Arrays.sort(array)`

Comment: Is my code write ? I just need to work in JOptionPane method ! and thanks so much ..

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
int min = min(min(num1,num2),num3);
int max = max(max(num1,num2),num3);
int mid = num1 + num2 + num3 - min - max;
System.out.println(min+"<="+mid+"<="+max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num1 < num2){ if(num3 < num1) System.out.println("num2 > num1 > num3");}
else{ if(num2 < num3) System.out.println("num3 > num2 > num1"); else System.out.println("num1 > num2 > num3");}
```

Sort in descending order.

Hope it helps.